# How to extract data value that is nested inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, helper

I am just trying to figure out why when trying to grab a value through the dot notation, it is giving me undefined error. Please see below for what I mean.

I am trying to extract the value from the nested object in the headline color array:

Comment: the json being parsed is incomplete or invalid. so whatever `el.selectgroup1[0]` is, it is not valid

Comment: The JSON.parse here is not useful (as the value given is not a string), I think based on your logged, that you can directly access the data using `el.selectgroup1[0].value`

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that `el.selectgroup1` is equal to some string value `"[{name: 'Off White', value: 'off-white'}]"`. then we can deduce that `el.selectgroup1[0]` is equal to `"["`. which would not be valid JSON within `JSON.parse("[")`.

Try something like `JSON.parse(el.selectgroup1)[0].value`

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, now I am getting this:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

I think it has something to do with race conditions